# Fatal error: Can't use function return value

Tags: php

When i'm using following code then fatal error generate.

```
echo empty(is_resource(true));
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) requires a variable as if the [parameter were passed by reference](http://php.net/language.references.pass):

> **Note:**
>   `empty()` only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

So you could do this:

```
$var = is_resource(true);
echo empty($var);
```

But as [`is_resource`](http://php.net/is_resource) already returns a boolean value, you actually don’t need another testing function.